# Any tip for start scraping an e-commerce site with RVEST?

Tags: web-scraping, e-commerce, rvest

I am trying to scrap some data from an ecommerce site using rvest. I haven't found any good examples to guide me. Any idea about it?

Let's put as an example how I started:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

#Specifying the url
url_base <- 'https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/'
#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

#Using CSS selectors to scrap the titles section
title_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.main-title')
#Converting the title data to text
title <- html_text(title_html)
head(title)

#Using CSS selectors to scrap the price section
price <- html_nodes(webpage,'.item__price')
price <- html_text(price)
price
```

So, I would like to do two basic things:

1. Entering in each product and take some data from them.
2. Pagination to all pages

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example for us to work on. As e-commerce websites usually have many live content, so the usual workflow it to use Rselenium and rvest. You can read Rselenium and rvest tutorial first and get a general idea of how to scrape websites.

Comment: Thank you Yifu, I have just put some minimal example. Meanwhile, I will have a look at Rselenium, I did not know it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrape that info is not difficult and is doable with rvest.
What you need to do is to get all the hrefs and loop on them. To do it, you need to use `html_attr()`

Following code should do the job:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

#Specifying the url
url_base <- 'https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/'
#You need to get href and loop on hrefs
all_pages <- url_base %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(".pagination__page > a") %>% html_attr("href")
all_pages[1] <- url_base
#create an empty table to store results
result_table <- tibble() 
for(page in all_pages){
    page_source <- read_html(page)
    title <- html_nodes(page_source,'.item__info-title') %>% html_text()
    price <- html_nodes(page_source,'.item__price') %>% html_text()
    item_link <- html_nodes(page_source,'.item__info-title') %>% html_attr("href")
    temp_table <- tibble(title = title, price = price, item_link = item_link)
    result_table <- bind_rows(result_table,temp_table)
}
```

After you get link to each item, you can loop on the item links.

[image]

### To View more pages

As you can see, there is a pattern in the suffix; you can simply add the number by 50 each time to navigate more pages.

```
> all_pages
[1] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/"          
[2] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_51" 
[3] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_101"
[4] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_151"
[5] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_201"
[6] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_251"
[7] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_301"
[8] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_351"
[9] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_401"
[10] "https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_451"
```

So we can do this:

```
str_c("https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_",seq.int(from = 51,by = 50,length.out = 40))
```

### Scrape each page

Let's use this page as an example: https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.uy/MLU-449598178-protector-funda-clear-cover-samsung-galaxy-note-8-_JM

```
pagesource <- read_html("https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.uy/MLU-449598178-protector-funda-clear-cover-samsung-galaxy-note-8-_JM")
n_vendor <- pagesource %>% html_node(".item-conditions") %>% html_text() %>% remove_nt()
product_description <- pagesource %>% html_node(".item-title__primary") %>% html_text() %>% remove_nt()
n_opinion <- pagesource %>% html_node(".average-legend span:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
product_price <- pagesource %>% html_nodes(".price-tag-fraction") %>% html_text()
current_table <- tibble(product_description = product_description, 
       product_price = product_price,
       n_vendor = n_vendor,
       n_opinion = n_opinion)
print(current_table)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
product_description                               product_price n_vendor   n_opinion
<chr>                                             <chr>         <chr>      <chr>    
    1 Protector Funda Clear Cover Samsung Galaxy Note 8 14            14vendidos 2
```

You can loop the code chunk above and get all info.

### Let's combine it all together

The following code should work, you can remove the 5-page limit to scrape all product information.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

#Specifying the url
url_base <- 'https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/'
#You need to get href and loop on hrefs
all_pages <- url_base %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(".pagination__page > a") %>% html_attr("href")
all_pages <- c(url_base,
               str_c("https://telefonia.mercadolibre.com.uy/accesorios-celulares/_Desde_",
                     seq.int(from = 51,by = 50,length.out = 40)))
#create an empty table to store results
result_table <- tibble() 
for(page in all_pages[1:5]){ #as an example, only scrape the first 5 pages
    page_source <- read_html(page)
    title <- html_nodes(page_source,'.item__info-title') %>% html_text()
    price <- html_nodes(page_source,'.item__price') %>% html_text()
    item_link <- html_nodes(page_source,'.item__info-title') %>% html_attr("href")
    temp_table <- tibble(title = title, price = price, item_link = item_link)
    result_table <- bind_rows(result_table,temp_table)
}

#loop on result table(item_link):
product_table <- tibble()
for(i in 1:nrow(result_table)){
    pagesource <- read_html(result_table[[i,"item_link"]])
    n_vendor <- pagesource %>% html_node(".item-conditions") %>% html_text() %>% remove_nt()
    product_description <- pagesource %>% html_node(".item-title__primary") %>% html_text() %>% remove_nt()
    currency_symbol <- pagesource %>% html_node(".price-tag-symbol") %>% html_text()
    n_opinion <- pagesource %>% html_node(".average-legend span:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
    product_price <- pagesource %>% html_nodes(".price-tag-fraction") %>% html_text()
    current_table <- tibble(product_description = product_description, 
                            currency_symbol = currency_symbol,
                            product_price = product_price,
                            n_vendor = n_vendor,
                            n_opinion = n_opinion,
                            item_link = result_table[[i,"item_link"]])
    product_table <- bind_rows(product_table,current_table)
}
```

Result:

[image]

### Some issues

There are still some bugs in the code, for example:
On this page, there are two items that match the css selector, which may break the code. There are some solutions though:

1. Store result in a list instead of a table
2. Use a more accurate CSS selector
3. concatenate string whenever there is more than one result and
   etc.
   [image]

You can choose any methods that fit your requirement.

Also, if you want to scrape in quantity, you may want to use `tryCatch` to prevent any errors from breaking your loop.

### About apis

Api is totally different with web scraping, you may want to read some more tutorials about api if you want to use it.

Comment: Thank you again Yifu!! It's working ... I have two more doubts:  1. Why it is scraping only 510 observation when there are many many more. 2. How can I get more info from inside the item, for example location, payment accepted, even the product description if possible.

Comment: You can observe that each page has 50 items and there is a pattern between suffix. I got the first 10 pages. As you get the link of each item, you can easily use `read_html()` to loop the item links and scrape in each item page.

Comment: Thank you again ! I see that this site has an API. Any recommendation about RVEST and SelectorGadget when having an API?      https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLU/search?category=MLU5726#json

Comment: It's totally different with api though. The methods are totally different.You can check out tutorial for "httr" package. Some tutorials are also available:[R api tutorial video](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/using-web-apis-from-r/), [Another api tutorial](https://tclavelle.github.io/blog/r_and_apis/). You can also search for other tutorials. If you want to stick with rvest, I updated the original answer, hope it's helpful.

Comment: That function is only used to adjust text formatting, sorry I forgot to include that in the script. You can safely remove that function,